# How to create a temporary file to helping cache large data in C++?

Tags: c++, caching, temporary

I have some large vectors, the data of them are coming from some calculations of hard disk files.
I've seen many softwares which uses a single temporary file to cache data.
I'm very curious about how to do this, but I don't know the name of this technique.
I want to change my codes as little as possible. 
Thank you.

My environment is Windows/MFC/VC10/Boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure you're looking for memory mapped files.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html

Comment: I saw that before, but it seems to be very complicated at first glance. Is there some demo code of this Boost class?

Comment: The following blog link contains a tarball which may be used as a demo code : http://codingplayground.blogspot.com/2009/03/memory-mapped-files-in-boost-and-c.html

Comment: I read the demo code in that page, but  I think mapped_file is just like a way of serialization? It means that I must maintain a list or something else to save/load object myself. I want an automatic method to do this without changing the existed code very much.   Thank you.